# Is there any reason that mean squared log error uses the natural log?

Tags: loss-functions, logarithm

[Mean Squared Logarithmic Error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#mean-squared-logarithmic-error) uses the natural log. Why not use log base 2 or 10, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [change of base property of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities),

$$\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a} = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}, $$

so changing from any fixed base $a$ to any other base $c$ (or $e$) simply means dividing by a *fixed* value $\log_c a$, so a change of base is just a scaling. All logarithms are equivalent.

The natural logarithm to base $e$ is very common and indeed *natural* in many other statistical and mathematical settings, so it's often the first thing that comes to mind to statisticians (computer scientists might indeed rather think first of base $2$, or engineers to base $10$).

Comment: One reason among several that it appears natural, or at least convenient, is that in statistics people reach for $\exp(x)$ much more than they do for $10^x$ or $2^x$; and then  $\ln()$ is the evident inverse. (You can tell a lot about researchers or communities by asking them what base they imagine if they see $\log()$.)